# Output of a CF Array

Tags: html, multidimensional-array, cfml

I have a simple "cart" that is updated by a user for a RFQ's. They array works fine and appending works good. However for some reason I can not seem to output the data into a table properly. My loop counter is working if that counts :) Please see my code below followed by the output I am trying to get to work I know this is simple and i'm over thinking it.

Thanks

```
<cfif isDefined("url.Series")>
    <cfset arrayAppend( session.cart, {Series = URL.Series , Style = URL.Style , Ohm = URL.Ohm , Notes = URL.Notes} )>
</cfif>

<a href="cleararray.cfm">Clear Array</a><br />
<a href="Stylesearch.cfm">Style Search</a><br /><br />

<h1><b>DEBUG:</b></h1>
<!--- Display current contents of cart --->
<cfdump var="#session.cart#" label="Cart Items">
<br />

<!--- Display items in cart in Table format --->
<table class="tftable" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Series</th>
        <th>Style ID</th>
        <th>Exact &#8486;</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Update</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
    <cfloop index="Series" from="1" to="#arraylen( session.cart )#">
        <tr>
        <td>#session.cart[Series]#</td>
        <td>#Style#</td>
        <td>#Ohm#</td>
        <td>Test Description</td>
        <td>#Notes#</td>
        <td>Test Quantity</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>^</td>
        </tr>
    </cfloop>
</table>
```

[image: CFDump]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to wrap your cfloop with a cfoutput.

```
<cfoutput>
<cfloop index="Series" from="1" to="#arraylen( session.cart )#">
    <tr>
    <td>#session.cart[Series]#</td>
    <td>#Style#</td>
    <td>#Ohm#</td>
    <td>Test Description</td>
    <td>#Notes#</td>
    <td>Test Quantity</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>^</td>
    </tr>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Personally I would also change the loop index to be different than 'Series' as it may get confusing later with the Series key in your cart's struct.

The first cell in the output `session.cart[Series]` will be the first struct in the cart whereas I think what you want is:
    `session.cart[Series].Series`.

Which is why I would change the loop index to `s` for example:

```
<cfoutput>
<cfloop index="s" from="1" to="#arrayLen( session.cart )#">
<cfset thisRow = session.cart[s] />
<tr>
<td>#thisRow.Series#</td>
<td>#thisRow.Style#</td>
<td>#thisRow.Ohm#</td>
<td>Test Description</td>
<td>#thisRow.Notes#</td>
<td>Test Quantity</td>
<td>X</td>
<td>^</td>
</tr>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Phipps, Thanks this worked great, I have a little follow up question, a example would probable help me save hours. I am going to write update functions for each line, how would I go about doing this as they need to address the proper row of the array. That is what the last two fields in the table will be (Update/Delete). Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are quite a few ways to do that. You would be better to create a cart.cfc that handles the adding/updating/deleting of items. Something like this: [Simple Shopping Cart](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/637-ask-ben-creating-a-simple-wish-list-shopping-cart.htm) It's a bit old but the principles are there. You then need to decide whether to go back to the server for each update (and reload the entire page) or use an async javascript request to post the data in the background and update the cart without a page reload.

Comment: Side note, if you do not need the index number for anything, you could also use an `array` loop (instead of `from/to`), so the `index` becomes the current array element, instead of a position.